# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un option al hacer un change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No soy muy bueno con javascript por eso quisiera saber como obtengo el nombre de un option al hacer un `change`:

Ejemplo:

```
<select id="ciudad">
 <option value="1">Monterrey</option>
 <option value="2">Tijuana</option>
 <option value="3">Mexico D.F</option>
</select>
```

Se que si hago lo siguiente `$(this).val();` y lo imprimo por consola, obtendré el valor del `option` al realizar el `change` pero, ¿cómo muestro el nombre?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
$('#ciudad').on('change', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var name = $('#ciudad option:selected').text();
  
  console.log(val)
  console.log(name)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ciudad">
 <option value="1">Monterrey</option>
 <option value="2">Tijuana</option>
 <option value="3">Mexico D.F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Excelente Men Gracias.

Comment: @Daniel con gusto, no te olvides marcar mi respuesta como correcta si te ha solucionado el problema

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo:

```js
$('#ciudad').change(function() {
  alert($(this).find('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ciudad">
    <option value="1">Monterrey</option>
    <option value="2">Tijuana</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico D.F</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimado colega, le dejo una opción en javascript puro, sin necesidad de importar algún tipo de librería. Es una opción que siempre me gusta considerar.

Saludos!.

PS: Código mejorado, gracias a la colaboración de Gustavo García.

```js
function ImprimirEnConsola(elemento){
  var seleccionada = elemento[elemento.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(seleccionada);
}
```

```html
<select id="ciudad" onchange="ImprimirEnConsola(this)">
 <option value="1">Monterrey</option>
 <option value="2">Tijuana</option>
 <option value="3">Mexico D.F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Si en lugar de pasarle el `value` del select le pasas el índice del elemento seleccionado, haces ese snippet funcional para todo select. `el.options[el.selectedIndex].textContent`.

Comment: Listo código mejorado, gracias Gustavo. Saludos!